# Intentar subir imagen en el producto con cloudinary y nodeJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, imagen, backend

Estoy creando el backend de una tienda ecommerce y tengo que validar las fotos. Empecé con una idea, pero mi profesor me ha hecho cambiar y ahora no se como unir lo que tengo hecho con lo que me pide. Os explico la situación:he creado una ruta especial para la subida de imagen a cloudinary. Este es el codigo:

````
    try {
        if(!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0)
            return res.status(400).json({msg: 'No files were uploaded.'})
        
        const file = req.files.file;
        if(file.size > 1024*1024) {
            removeTmp(file.tempFilePath)
            return res.status(400).json({msg: "Size too large"})
        }

        if(file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/png'){
            removeTmp(file.tempFilePath)
            return res.status(400).json({msg: "File format is incorrect."})
        }

        cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(file.tempFilePath, {folder: "ecommerce"}, async(err, result)=>{
            if(err) throw err;

            removeTmp(file.tempFilePath)

            res.json({public_id: result.public_id, url: result.secure_url})
        })


    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
    }
})

const removeTmp = (path) =>{
    fs.unlink(path, err=>{
        if(err) throw err;
    })
} ``` 



Tengo un modelo de producto hecho de esta manera : 




```const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    price:{
        type: Number,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    images:{
        type: Object,
        required: true
     
    },
    category:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Category",
        required: true
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
})


module.exports = mongoose.model("Products", productSchema)
````

Y esta es mi función para crear el producto :

```
        try {
            const {
                name,
                price,
                images,
                description,
                categoryId
            } = req.body;
              
           

            if (!images) return res.status(400).json({
                message: "No hay imagen del producto!"
            })

            if (!(name || price || description))
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: "Por favor, complete todos los campos"
                })

            const product = await Products.findOne({
                name
            })
            if (product)
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: "Este producto ya ha sido creado anteriormente"
                })

            const newProduct = new Products({
                name: name.toLowerCase(),
                price,
                description,
                categoryId,
                images
            })

            await newProduct.save()
            res.json({
                message: "Producto creado ! "
            })

        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: err.message
            })
        }
    }
```

El tema es que, primero subía la imagen, y a la hora de crear el producto , le pasaba por Postman los resultados de la subida de la imagen( public_id y la url) .

En la revisión mi profesor me dijo de juntar todo en una misma ruta, la de crear el producto , llevo toda la mañana intentandolo y no hay manera de que me funcione. Alguien me puede ayudar ?
No se exactamente como debería de quedar la función con la imagen integrada.

Reciba un cordial saludo, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Hola debes unir los 2 controladores en uno solo, y en el nuevo controlador que te quede, debes manejar todo y enviar a esa ruta tanto el nombre, precio, descripción, categoría y el archivo de la imagen en un mismo formulario

```
try {
    if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0)
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No files were uploaded.' })

    const file = req.files.file;
    if (file.size > 1024 * 1024) {
        removeTmp(file.tempFilePath)
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Size too large" })
    }

    if (file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/png') {
        removeTmp(file.tempFilePath)
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "File format is incorrect." })
    }

    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(file.tempFilePath, { folder: "ecommerce" }, async (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        removeTmp(file.tempFilePath)

        // res.json({public_id: result.public_id, url: result.secure_url})

        const {
            name,
            price,
            // images,
            description,
            categoryId
        } = req.body;

        const images = {
            public_id: result.public_id,
            url: result.secure_url
        }

        if (!images) return res.status(400).json({
            message: "No hay imagen del producto!"
        })

        if (!(name || price || description))
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: "Por favor, complete todos los campos"
            })

        const product = await Products.findOne({
            name
        })
        if (product)
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: "Este producto ya ha sido creado anteriormente"
            })

        const newProduct = new Products({
            name: name.toLowerCase(),
            price,
            description,
            categoryId,
            images
        })

        await newProduct.save()
        res.json({
            message: "Producto creado ! "
        })
    })

} catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message })
}
```

Este código sería un ejemplo tal vez no te funcione pero es para que tegas un ejemplo.

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto !! Muchas gracias ! No era exactamente asi, pero si que por ese camino que me has dicho tenia que ir ! Mil gracias